# Why is my iOS device calling Google safe browsing?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

I'm currently using `NextDNS` as a "pihole" on my device. And recently, while checking my logs, I noticed that my device has been calling Google safe browsing api for the past month

> safebrowsing.googleapis.com

[image: Description]

I then got concerned as I have completely disabled `Fraudulent Website Warning` under Safari settings. I have also checked with `NextDNS` and they told me this is not coming from them either.

After that, I blocked all outgoing queries from them. I then also viewed in the logs that this is happening even when the phone is asleep.

I don't have any google apps whatsoever, and have very little installed apps. I've been trying to think what is causing this. I haven't hard reset yet, as I want to mitigate the issue.

Do you think this could be an iOS issue or what else?

Thanks!

Comment: What  apps have you installed? Something like Charles proxy on iOS might tell you more about the specific request and exact timing so you could see which app was foreground when these are asked.

Answer (score 2):

NextDNS has an option for Google Safe Browsing. It's on by default but you can disable it from the nextdns.io dashboard.

Comment: Thank you. This however, was the first thing I disabled. And they said if this option is enabled, you won't see any queries, as it's done server side.